# How to setup a different leading/trailing constraint constant for iPhone 6+?

Tags: ios, autolayout, spacing

I have noticed that the leading/trailing spacing for iPhone 6+ and iPhone 5/5s/6 is different. To be specific 5/5s/6 needs -16px from leading/trailing to fit the screen, while the 6+ uses -20px. What should I do to fix this problem?

So, far the only thing that came to mind was to add two constraints (-16px and -20px) for Leading and Trailing and put the -20px one with different priority. But it didn't change anything. What else can I try?

Comment: Try to remove the check Constrain to margins when adding constraints

Comment: Thank you! I wish I can see a use case for using margins for a superview (it is checked by default)...